# How to get values from MySQL database with PHP code using WHERE clause and variable set from url

Tags: php, mysql

I want to get survey questions from MySQL database, where pollid=1 and echo them out.

I have following code:

```
<?php
include_once 'init/init.funcs.php';
$pollid=$_GET['pollid'];
$result = mysql_query('SELECT kysimus FROM kysimused where survey_id="1"');
$question = mysql_result($result, 0);
echo $pollid;
echo $question;

?>
```

It works and I see first question from database, where survey_id =1. But when I write:

```
<?php
include_once 'init/init.funcs.php';
$pollid=$_GET['pollid'];
$result = mysql_query('SELECT kysimus FROM kysimused where survey_id="$pollid"');
$question = mysql_result($result, 0);
echo $pollid;
echo $question;

?>
```

It says:

```
Warning: mysql_result() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\xampp2\htdocs\Praks\answering.php on line 5
```

In last example I inserted pollid from url and I am sure that variable $pollid got value '1'. Why the second code doesnt work? I have second question too, how could I create an array of all the questions, which have survey_id = $pollid.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use double quotes if you want to pass variable into a statement. Double quotes for the statement and single quotes for the variable.

Comment: to elaborate on @iamsleepy 's answer, because you used single quotes it's trying to find the VALUE "$pollid" rather than the value contained within the variable. also, use parameter binding, mysqli or pdo, etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Single quote strings do not parse variables, change this:

`$result = mysql_query('SELECT kysimus FROM kysimused where survey_id="$pollid"');`

for this:

`$result = mysql_query('SELECT kysimus FROM kysimused where survey_id="' . $pollid . '"');`

Also dont forget to sanitize your input, something like this would be better:

`$result = mysql_query('SELECT kysimus FROM kysimused where survey_id="' . (int)$pollid . '"');`

at least to make sure its an int

Answer (score 1):

rewrite your query line as follows:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT kysimus FROM kysimused where survey_id='$pollid'");
```

This is due to the handling of single and double quotes in php....
The way you wrote it is the reason the variable does not get substituted.

Please see also: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php

more detailed: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing this

```
$result = mysql_query('SELECT kysimus FROM kysimused where survey_id="$pollid"');
```

with

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT kysimus FROM kysimused where survey_id='$pollid' ");
```